# Name ''enumerator' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

```
namespace ProiectBDD
{
    public partial class AdaugaIntrebari : UserControl
    {
        private string connstring;

        public string Connstring
        {
            get { return connstring; }
            set { connstring = value; }
        }

        public AdaugaIntrebari(string p_connstring)
        {
            connstring = p_connstring;
            InitializeComponent();
            IncarcaCategorii();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                label1.Text = enumerator.Current.Categorie;
            }
        }

        public void IncarcaCategorii()
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var q = from a in dc.GetTable<Categorii>()
                    select a;
            var enumerator = q.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

I get Name `enumerator` does not exist in current context error in my button event handler 
method.

Comment: well it's because there is no enumerator defined in the I see.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory

Comment: It is defined in method incarcaCategorii

Comment: Oh I see, you should be unaware of scopes I suppose. take a look at Naham's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button1_Click` doesn't know about `enumerator` because it exists only in IncarcaCategorii
you need to make it a class field

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;

namespace ProiectBDD
{
    public partial class AdaugaIntrebari : UserControl
    {
        private string connstring;
        private IEnumerator<DataRow> _enumerator;

        public string Connstring
        {
            get { return connstring; }
            set { connstring = value; }
        }

        public AdaugaIntrebari(string p_connstring)
        {
            connstring = p_connstring;
            InitializeComponent();
            IncarcaCategorii();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_enumerator == null) return;

            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                label1.Text = _enumerator.Current.Categorie;
            }
        }

        public void IncarcaCategorii()
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var q = from a in dc.GetTable<Categorii>()
                    select a;
            _enumerator = q.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`enomerator` variable doesn't exist in the scope

See this method:

```
public void IncarcaCategorii()
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var q = from a in dc.GetTable<Categorii>()
            select a;
    var enumerator = q.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
} // This is where "enumerator" become subject to garbage collection
```

`enumerator` variable needs to be passed in here somehow:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        label1.Text = enumerator.Current.Categorie;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label1.Text = enumerator.Current.Categorie.[FieldName];
```

or maybe current position of your `IEnumerator` is out of context, select object again